# Chef recipe not found for cookbook

Tags: postgresql, chef-infra

I am trying to use Chef's PostgreSQL cookbook:
https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/postgresql#readme

I am getting this error:

```
Chef::Exceptions::RecipeNotFound: could not find recipe default for cookbook postgresql
```

I don't see a default.rb in the repo:
https://github.com/sous-chefs/postgresql/find/main

I've added the dependencies to Berksfile and metadata.rb and in my recipe added:

```
include_recipe 'postgresql'
```

I also added a default.rb to my repo and `include_recipe 'postgresql'` to that.
Still keeps saying no default recipe. Am I missing something here?

**Edit:**

Based on seshadri_c's answer, this is error is now gone.
I'm trying to install extension.
Have this in my default.rb:

```
postgresql_extension 'postgres adminpack' do 
   database 'postgres' 
   extension 'adminpack' 
end
```

But get error

```
FATAL: NoMethodError: postgresql_extension[postgres adminpack] (******::default line 5) had an error: NoMethodError: bash[CREATE EXTENSION postgres adminpack] (/tmp/packer-chef-solo/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/postgresql/resources/extension.rb line 31) had an error: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass[0m
```

Answer (score 1):

A major change was introduced in the postgresql cookbook v7.0. Quoting from supermarket page:

> If you are wondering where all the recipes went in v7.0+, or how on earth I use this new cookbook please see upgrading.md for a full description.

In short, all of the cookbooks functionality has been moved from recipes to [custom resources](https://github.com/sous-chefs/postgresql/tree/main/resources).

So, now the correct way to reuse that functionality is to "invoke" the appropriate resource instead of "including" recipes.

Example to install PostgreSQL client from `my_pg_client` cookbook:

**In `my_pg_client/metadata.rb`**:

```rb
depends 'postgresql' # version pin as required
```

**Then in `my_pg_client/recipes/default.rb`**:

```rb
# Install client software

postgresql_client_install 'My PostgreSQL Client install' do
  version '9.5'
end
```

There are other similar custom resources, if you want to install server for example:

```rb
postgresql_server_install 'My PostgreSQL Server install' do
  version '9.5'
  action :install
end
```

There are a number of examples on how to use the [custom resources](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources/) in: https://github.com/sous-chefs/postgresql/tree/main/test/cookbooks/test/recipes

*Update*:

The `postgresql_extension` resource by default installs extension which is supplied as the name to the resource. So, the `extension 'adminpack'` property can be omitted. You could try something like:

```rb
# Considering that a DB called "postgres" exists

postgresql_extension 'adminpack' do
  database 'postgres'
end
```

Comment: Thanks. That error is now gone. Have another error now trying to install extension. Not sure if you are also familiar with this?

Comment: I'm not too sure, but have you created the database and user though?

Comment: Yes, the DB and users have been created in a separate existing recipe. The default.rb is created to just install extension using PostgreSQL cookbook then, but currently fails.

Comment: I've updated the answer, you could try changing the resource name as I have. Not too sure it'll fix the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately still same result. Still get that undefined method error.